# NSUserDefaultsApp Groups WatchKit swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I try to write a small test app to communicate between iPhone and Watch, using NSUserdefaults. But it still doesn't work after attempt lots of solutions. So I post my code here to ask for help. Thank you!

iPhone side:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var addLabel: UILabel!

var n : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func addBtn(sender: AnyObject) {        
    n++
    addLabel.text = "\(n)"     
}

@IBAction func sendBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mySharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.sunyi.sharingdatasunyi")

    mySharedDefaults?.setInteger(n, forKey: "savedUserInput")

    mySharedDefaults?.synchronize()
}
```

}

And the Watch side:
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

```
@IBOutlet var myWatchLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)      
    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

@IBAction func showBtn() {

    let mySharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.sunyi.sharingdatasunyi")

    mySharedDefaults?.synchronize()

    var a : Int = -1

    a = mySharedDefaults!.integerForKey("savedUserInput")

    self.myWatchLabel.setText("\(a)")

}
```

}

I have built the App Groups and the ID is group.com.sunyi.sharingdatasunyi. The project name is sharingdatasunyi. The Bundle ID is com.sunyi.sharingdatasunyi. Finally the result is: whatever I input on the iPhone side, after press the ShowButton on watch, the label always displays 0 (not -1, not my input number). So, how could I do?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have turn on the switch for App Groups in the Capabilities item, for both sharingdatasunyi and WatchKit Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using watchOS 1 or 2? On watchOS 2 you can't use NSUserDefaults to communicate between the watch and iPhone, even if they are using a shared group. You should look into using [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-713/) and sendMessage to communicate in real time between the two devices.

Comment: Really? I used watchOS 2. Oh... But I find by using WatchConnectivities, the communication between iPhone and Watch could not be in real time. Sometimes the message sent from watch to phone had more than 10 seconds delay, either by simulator or by real devices. So, thank you for your valuable reminder, sincerely! Would you please tell me how to make the communication in real time? still rely on WatchConnectivies, or is there any other solution? Thank you very much and wait for you further suggestion!

Comment: WatchConnectivity's sendMessage is the fastest way for the devices to communicate in watchOS 2. It should be able to send a message much faster than 10 seconds. I am guessing you are sending a large message? Try sending a small one to see if you can get better speeds and if you can, you will likely need to reduce the size of your message (remove unneeded data or compress it).

Comment: Not large a message at all, an integer or a string less 5 characters. Using WatchConnectivities, the message from iPhone to Watch can be sent in real time. But from Watch to iPhone was really delayed. I used the sentence just like             session.sendMessage(["b":"Goodbye"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)        pretty simple. So do you know the season? Thank you very much again!